# Java: @PathVariable seems to not pass to url

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to pass the id from my group model to the url so i can add member to a specific group. and store in my database.  The interesting thing is if i was to directly type in the group id into the url /member/add/1 the jsp page renders and i am able to add a member to the specific group with id of 1.

**Controller Code:**

````
    @GetMapping("/member/add/{group_id}")
    public String addMember(
            @PathVariable("group_id") Long group_id,
            @ModelAttribute ("newMember")Member newMember, 
            Principal principal,
            Model model
            ) {
                Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
                logger.debug("Received group_id: {}", group_id);
                TheGroup group = gService.findGroupById(group_id);
                model.addAttribute("group", group);
                //logger.info("This is an information message." +  group_id);
        return "addMember.jsp";
    }```


    **Group Service code:** 
    ``` 
        public TheGroup findGroupById(Long group_id) {
            Optional<TheGroup> g = gRepo.findById(group_id);
            if(g.isPresent()) {
                return g.get();
            }else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Group not found");
                // return null;
            }
        }```

    **jsp code:** 
    ```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <!--For: c:out, c:forEach, etc...  -->
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
        <!--For: FORM -->
        <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
            <!--For: rendering Errors on PUT routes  -->
            <%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
                <!-- DATE -->
                <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>

                    <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <title>Attendance Application | Dashboard </title>

                        <!-- for Bootstrap CSS -->
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
                        <!-- YOUR own local CSS -->
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
                        <!-- For any Bootstrap that uses JS or jQuery-->
                        <script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <!--Side Bar  -->
                            <div class="sidebar">
                                <div class="flex-nowrap sidebar-content">
                                    <div class="bg-dark">
                                        <div
                                            class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                                            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start"
                                                id="menu">
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a href="/user/dashboard" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                                                        <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">
                                                            Zion Attendance
                                                        </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="/member/add/${group.id}"
                                                        class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                                                        <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Add Member</span></a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="/attendance/status" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                                                        <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Attendance</span></a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                                                        <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Goals</span></a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Main   -->
                            <div class="main">
                                <!-- Navigation Bar  -->
                                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary bg-primary">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <!-- <c:forEach var="group" items="${groups}">
                                            <li class="w-100">
                                                <a href="/group/${group.id}" class="nav-link px-0">
                                                    <c:out value="${group.name }"></c:out>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </c:forEach> -->
                                        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="/user/dashboard">
                                            <c:out value="${group.name }"></c:out>
                                        </a> -->
                                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                            data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
                                            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

                                            <div class="dropdown me-auto">
                                                <a href="#"
                                                    class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle"
                                                    id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    <!-- <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle"> -->
                                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">
                                                        <c:out value="${currentUser.firstName}"></c:out>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small text-white shadow"
                                                    aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New Group...</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                                        <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="/logout">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                                                                value="${_csrf.token}" />
                                                            <input type="submit" class="dropdown-item"
                                                                value="Logout!" />
                                                        </form>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li> -->
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                                <main class="content">
                                    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                                        <div class="row mb-2 mb-xl-3 ">
                                            <div class="col-12 d-none d-sm-block ">
                                                <h3>
                                                    <c:out value="${groupName.name }"></c:out> Dashboard
                                                </h3>
                                                <div>
                                                    <p style="color: black"> Group Leader: <c:out
                                                            value="${currentUser.firstName }"></c:out>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 d-flex py-2">
                                                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/759x360" alt="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                            </div>
                            </main>
                        </div>

                        <!--Footer  -->

                        <footer class="bg-primary fixed-bottom">
                            <ul class="nav justify-content-center ">
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Features</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">FAQs</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">&copy; 2023 Timothy Singleton, Inc</p>
                        </footer>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                            function updateDateSelected() {
                                const newDate = document.querySelector("#datePicker").value;

                                const hiddenDateInput = document.querySelector(".hiddenDateInput");

                                hiddenDateInput.value = newDate;
                            }
                        </script>
                    </body>

                    </html>
````

when trying to navigate to the route the url looks like this: localhost:8080/member/add/

Im not sure if i am doing anything wrong here.

just in case this may help

**Group Repo:**

```
`public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<TheGroup, Long> {
    List<TheGroup> findAll();
    Optional<TheGroup> findByName(String name);
    Optional<TheGroup> findById(Long group_id);
    TheGroup findByGroupleader(User currentUser);
    List<Member> findByMembers(Long id);
```

}```

**Add Memeber Jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!--For: c:out, c:forEach, etc...  -->
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!--For: FORM -->
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
        <!--For: rendering Errors on PUT routes  -->
        <%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
            <!-- DATE -->
            <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>

                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>Attendance Application | Add Member </title>

                    <!-- for Bootstrap CSS -->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
                    <!-- YOUR own local CSS -->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
                    <!-- For any Bootstrap that uses JS or jQuery-->
                    <script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                </head>

                <body>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <!--Side Bar  -->
                        <div class="sidebar">
                            <div class="flex-nowrap sidebar-content">
                                <div class="bg-dark">
                                    <div
                                        class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start"
                                            id="menu">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a href="/user/dashboard" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                                                    <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">
                                                        Zion Attendance
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a href="/attendance/status" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                                                    <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span
                                                        class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Attendance</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Main   -->
                        <div class="main">
                            <!-- Navigation Bar  -->
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary bg-primary">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Attendance Application</a>
                                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                        data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
                                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Link 1</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>


                                            </li>

                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="dropdown me-auto">
                                            <a href="#"
                                                class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle"
                                                id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <!-- <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle"> -->
                                                <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">
                                                    <c:out value="${currentUser.firstName}"></c:out>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small text-white shadow"
                                                aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="/logout">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                                                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
                                                        <input type="submit" class="dropdown-item"
                                                            value="Logout!" />
                                                    </form>
                                                </li>
                                                <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li> -->
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                            <main class="content">
                                <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                                    <div class="row mb-2 mb-xl-3 ">
                                        <div class="col-12 d-none d-sm-block ">
                                            <h3>New Member</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex py-2">
                                            <div class="card flex-fill w-100">
                                                <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title mb-0"> Add Members</h5>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <form:form action="/member/add" method="post"
                                                        modelAttribute="newMember">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="${group.id}" />
                                                        <div>
                                                            <form:label path="fName">First Name:</form:label>
                                                            <form:input path="fName" class="form-control me-2"
                                                                type="text" placeholder=""
                                                                aria-label="Add a Member" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <form:label path="lName">Last Name:</form:label>
                                                            <form:input path="lName" class="form-control me-2"
                                                                type="text" placeholder=""
                                                                aria-label="Add a Member" />
                                                        </div>

                                                        <input type="submit" value="add member" class="my-2" />
                                                    </form:form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </main>
                        </div>

                        <!--Footer  -->

                        <footer class="bg-primary fixed-bottom">
                            <ul class="nav justify-content-center ">
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Features</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">FAQs</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">&copy; 2023 Timothy Singleton, Inc</p>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        function updateDateSelected() {
                            const newDate = document.querySelector("#datePicker").value;

                            const hiddenDateInput = document.querySelector(".hiddenDateInput");

                            hiddenDateInput.value = newDate;
                        }
                    </script>
                </body>

                </html>
```

**UserController**

```
    @GetMapping("/user/dashboard")
public String dashboard(
    Principal principal,    
    Model model
    ){
        String username = principal.getName();
        User currentUser = uService.findByUsername(username);
        
        TheGroup group = gService.findByGroupleader(currentUser); // Assuming findByGroupleader returns a single group for the currentUser

        if (group != null) {
            List<Member> groupMembers = gService.findGroupMembers(group.getId());
            
            model.addAttribute("currentUser", group.getGroupleader());
            model.addAttribute("groupMembers", groupMembers);
            model.addAttribute("groupName", group);
            
        }
        return "userDashboard2.jsp";
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you please share more code of Jsp like from where you getting Group Object.. it looks like group object's groupId is eighter empty or null

Comment: As requested i added my full jsp page. @Yogesh

Comment: looks like based on code this is main page and from this page you click on add member ModelAttribute is missing in this page and could you please confirm that group object is getting pass from API where this JSP page gets return.. or you can share  the API details from which this JSP page gets return

Comment: i added the jsp that is suppose to return when clicked on the link. but here is the thing on the main jsp i am able to get the group name to that page from the Users controller so i assume the group object is already passed in on that page if im able to do that. so my thought was why cant i just grab the id and pass to where i need it to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your jsp form action described as `/members/add`

```
<form:form action="/member/add" method="post" modelAttribute="newMember">
```

There are no @PathVariable after '/add' part.
`group_id` is passed as body value together with your newMember data.
You should make controller mapping same as action attribute, and change @PathVariable to @RequestParam.

An another option is to change `action` to be concatenated with needed value:

```
 <form:form action="/member/add/${group.id}" method="post" modelAttribute="newMember">
```

Comment: Prior to me sending this code block I had what you mention that way and it still doesn’t work. My issue is getting the page it’s to load so I can fill out the form and it seems that everything seem right on my GetMapping route

Comment: Have you tried second option by changing action attribute of your form?

Comment: The problem with @PathVariable - it is required by default, and as you said form will redirect you to the "member/add" path where spring will not handle your request due to PathVariable absence

Comment: actually now i am getting this error: Required request parameter 'group_id' for method parameter type Long is present but converted to null.  This is happening when I use the @RequestParam and my route looks like this /member/add?group_id=${group.id}

Comment: Have you checked the route where request is sent by browser ?
If it still `/member/add?group_id=${group.id}`, then please provide your controller code where you're expecting this group_id parameter

Comment: here is the controller code: `@GetMapping("/member/add")
 public String addMember(
  @RequestParam("group_id") Long group_id,
  @ModelAttribute ("newMember")Member newMember, 
  Principal principal,
  Model model
   ) {
  return "addMember.jsp";
 }`     And it says its present but converted into null